# Transfer protected range permission from manager to manager automatically

Tags: permissions, protected-folders

There are 400+ spreadsheets with almost 50 multiple tabs inside one spreadsheet. All these tabs are protected. I was given the permission of the drive as a "Manager", however, I need to change the permission from the previous employee to me as I took over the job position. The problem is when I want to edit a protected sheet, it doesn't allow me as I can only "view" them, so I had to manually transfer the permission so I can edit but there are a lot of files. I need to have access to all spreadsheet automatically. I don't know how to use the Apps Script and I am asking for your support to work with google sheet more efficiently.

I need to have access to all spreadsheet automatically so I can edit. I don't know how to use the Apps Script and I am asking for your support to work with google sheet more efficiently.